# How can i find where checkin and checkout are crossing each other (Overbooking)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a MYSQL table that looks like this

```
---------------------------------------------
id | checkin            | checkout
---------------------------------------------
1  |2015-12-15 14:00:00 | 2015-12-19 11:00:00
2  |2016-01-17 14:00:00 | 2016-01-19 11:00:00
3  |2015-10-29 14:00:00 | 2015-11-01 11:00:00
4  |2015-10-30 14:00:00 | 2015-11-05 11:00:00
```

So for example id 3 is crossing with id 4 which means it is overbooked what query can i write to detect it? Thanks

Comment: You can try `select id, count(*) occured from table group by checkin, checkout`

Comment: "select * from table where checkin > checkout" - you will get if any crossing exists

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table against itself where the checkin is between checkin and checkout.

Simple way with an OR in the join condition

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b
ON (b.checkin BETWEEN a.checkin AND a.checkout
OR b.checkout BETWEEN a.checkin AND a.checkout)
AND a.id != b.id
```

Using a UNION which might be more efficient.

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b
ON b.checkin BETWEEN a.checkin AND a.checkout
AND a.id != b.id
UNION
SELECT *
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b
ON b.checkout BETWEEN a.checkin AND a.checkout
AND a.id != b.id
```

EDIT

If the time bands can have the same recorded checkin / check out without being regarded as overlapping:-

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b
ON b.checkin > a.checkin AND b.checkin < a.checkout
AND a.id != b.id
UNION
SELECT *
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b
ON b.checkout > a.checkin AND b.checkout < a.checkout
AND a.id != b.id
```

EDIT again

If you only want to count the date parts:-

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b
ON DATE(b.checkin) > DATE(a.checkin) AND DATE(b.checkin) < DATE(a.checkout)
AND a.id != b.id
UNION
SELECT *
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b
ON DATE(b.checkout) > DATE(a.checkin) AND DATE(b.checkout) < DATE(a.checkout)
AND a.id != b.id
```

Comment: This is giving me 38420 results which is really wrong. there should be only around 20 maximum

Comment: Try the first one now (missed the brackets around the 2 OR checks). 2nd one didn't suffer this error.

Comment: It works with the test data you have given when I try it. Returns 2 rows, one for id 3 overlapping with 4, and the other for id 4 overlapping with 3 (easy to avoid that if you only want them reported once)

Comment: My Datetime have hours. maybe thats why i see alot of results. how can i select as dates without the hours?

Comment: So does my test data. However is the data only important down to the hour (ie, if one checkout is at the same day / hour as the next checkin do you want to ignore those?)

Comment: @ВалерийШубкин - Just added a solution for that. You have to use < or > rather than BETWEEN,

Comment: And how can i make it compare only the dates, without time? because it is showing me 27800 results now. in real its only abour 38..

Comment: Change it to compare _DATE(b.checkout)_ , to truncate the date / times to just dates.